# How to set VideoView in Bundle when retrieving

Tags: java, android, video, bundle, android-videoview

I have tried using this syntax but it depicts that "Cannot resolve method 'into(android.widget.VideoView)'" when retrieving video (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EScos.png)

I want to retrieve video in VideoView as well as its TextView from one layout to another layout after a user clicking on the data to view more details about the data at the other page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know how to implement VideoView in Bundle where i want video can retrieve to another page